# How to get Japan time in shell script file in windows?

Tags: shell

I want to get Japan time in my shell script. I am using this command

```
DATE=`TZ=Japan date +"%Y%d%m%H%M"`
echo "Japan Date - "$DATE
```

This is working on online shell script execution. But if I try this in my .sh file, its giving wrong datetime.

Kindly suggest on the same.

Comment: FYI -- you don't need to put `Japan Date -` in quotes (though it's perfectly safe to do so). You **do** need to put `$DATE` in quotes to prevent its expansion from being modified by contents in IFS. (And as a general rule, all-caps variable names are reserved, and shouldn't be used for your own variables). Try your code with and without `IFS=12345` previously run to see what difference it makes when `$DATE` is outside quotes.

Comment: Fixing the capitalization and quoting, and switching to the official timezone name of JST, we get `date=$(TZ=JST date '+%Y%d%m%H%M'); echo "Japan Date - $date"`

Comment: ...re the "all-caps variable names are reserved" assertion, see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, keeping in mind that setting a regular shell variable overwrites any like-named environment variable; so to be sure you never overwrite a system-provided environment variable by mistake, you need to keep regular shell variables out of the namespace reserved for them.

Comment: One does not need to quote a variable expansion when the value consists of nothing but 12 digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code which I mentioned above works fine in UNIX environment. I was executing it in windows environment which is not correct. The identifier "TZ=Japan" only identified by UNIX environment. So once again, below code works fine

DATE=`TZ=Japan date +"%Y%d%m%H%M"`
echo "Japan Date - "$DATE

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to get the GMT time:

```
$date=[System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId($(Get-Date), [System.TimeZoneInfo]::Local.Id, 'GMT Standard Time')
```

And this one to get Japanese time and add 9 hours to the time:

```
$TimeRaised = ([datetime]$date).AddHours(9).ToString('dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm')
```

Comment: You might explicitly mention this as a powershell answer, since the OP didn't say _which_ shell they were using, and their original code in the question is for POSIX-family shells.